# CSS class depending on page position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

I have a fixed navigation at the top of the page that has links that smoothly scroll you around to different sections (IDs) of the page via jQuery.

Would there be any possible way to have a css class (e.g. .current) appended to the navigation links depending on what section of the page you're at?

For example, when I click "About", it'll scroll down to the About section and also make the navigation text orange as long as you stay in that section?

I've seen this done somewhere a while ago but I don't remember the website or even how to describe this behavior to search for it.

EDIT: Here's a link to something siliar to what I'm looking for:
http://www.fat-man-collective.com/hello.php

The icons change depending on your position on the page.

Script:

```
<script> 
  function goToByScroll(id){
  $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top - 50},'500');
  }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="goToByScroll('about')">About</a>

[...]

<div id="about">
  [...]
</div>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This would be possible by examing the `offset()`* function of the desired element and then coding to respond accordingly. You can track the offset of an element, and depending on the resulting offset, you would apply or remove the appropriate classes accordingly.

*See the documentation for [offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)

Comment: Thanks... I can see this working but I'm not very knowledgeable of javascript. I'm not seeing an example in the documentation of how to apply classes/remove classes depending on the offset; only getting the offset.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on a section in the navigation, just modify the class so that the style is what you want it to be.

Secondly, you'll need to add an event handler on the `scroll` event that similar modifies the nav's class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function goToByScroll(id){

    $('ul#nav li a').removeClass('active'); // elements in menu
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top - 50},'500');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Four years later...for those that have the same question since hopefully the OP has solved his problem by now.

Check out Bootstrap's [ScrollSpy](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy) plugin, which "is for automatically updating nav targets based on scroll position."  For an example of using the ScrollSpy plugin see [this detailed tutorial](http://www.codingeverything.com/2014/02/BootstrapDocsSideBar.html) on how to make a floating, updating navbar (like the Bootstrap site uses).